# how to set target for a file/bundle in xcconfig file

Tags: xcode, configuration, target, xcconfig

As we known, we can set target membership for a certain file/bundle in right navigator of xcode.

But now I want to set target membership in a certain configuration. So how can I set target for a file/bundle in xcconfig file?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a build phase that:

- runs before you copy bundles phase.
- It would detect whether the config is Debug vs Release using ${CONFIGURATION}
- and then copy the file into a location/name where it would then get picked up by the copy files phase.